# The right way to define a custom object properties?

Tags: c#, object

I am currently defining custom object properties as follows:

```
private int count;
public int Count
{
    get { return count; }
    set { Count = value; }
}
```

my fist part of the question is there any difference between defining fields like that and like:

```
private int count;
public int Count {get; set;}
```

unless you want to check something about the value as so:

```
private int count;
public int Count
{
    get { return count; }
    set
    {
        if (value >= 0)
        {
            count = value;;
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Value is negative", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

And the second part is is there a better way of defining object properties in C#?

Comment: Doesn't get better than `public int Count {get; set;}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because all of this is explained in official documentation. Consult that first https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example you define a private field and a property to access it. In your second example you define a private field and an *auto*-property that has **its own backing field**. So yes, there is a difference.

Unless you need custom `get/set` logic as in your final example, I would use the auto-property. However you shouldn't have a separate backing field (since it is independent of the property) so your code would just be:

```
public int Count {get; set;}
```

In either case (full or auto); you are using the correct way of defining properties in C#. The only thing I would add is that if you have `get` only properties, you can use expression-bodied members in C#6+:

```
public string Title => "Title"; //basically public string Title {get;} = "Title";
```

This is can be *more* efficient then the similar property because it doesn't use a backing field.

Comment: Strictly speaking the expression-bodied property isn't exactly equivalent to `public string Title { get; } = "Title"`.  The latter will result in a readonly backing field that will store the string `"Title"` while the former won't create a backing field.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks, modified to reflect that.